# Grails 3.0.9. How can I test Hibernate second level caching?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-3.0

How can I test Hibernate second level caching?

I tried to configure it in application.yml:

```
hibernate:
cache:
    use_second_level_cache: true
    provider_class: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
    region:
        factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
flush:
    mode: 'commit'
```

Tracing option `dataSource {
           ...
            logSql = true
        }`, it always shows the execution SQL? Or also includes an extract from the second level cache without the execution SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could activate org.hibernate.cache [category](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) to log all second-level cache activity.

To do so edit your Config.groovy file. Find the line with:

```
hibernate = "off"
```

and replace it with:

```
hibernate.cache = "trace,stdout"
```

You can also have a look of grails [FAQ](https://grails.org/wiki/FAQ#Q%3a%20How%20can%20I%20turn%20on%20logging%20for%20hibernate%20in%20order%20to%20see%20SQL%20statements,%20input%20parameters%20and%20output%20results?) for this.

Edit : use of statistics API

To browse the contents of a second-level or query cache region, use the Statistics API:

```
Map cacheEntries = sessionFactory.getStatistics()
    .getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(regionName)
    .getEntries();
```

You will need to enable statistics and, optionally, force Hibernate to keep the cache entries in a more readable format:

```
hibernate.generate_statistics true
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries true
```

Hope this helps! Thanks

Comment: Alas, placement in Grails 3.0 other configuration

Comment: I have edited my answer and added some info on statistics API, hope that helps.